# Authorization using fetch API

Tags: javascript, authorization, fetch

How can I send authorization credentials using fetch?

It worked using postman but on Chrome I keep receiving this message:

> `Request cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define `user:pass@host` in the URL. Just set the Authorization http Header:

```
var headers = new Headers();

headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password));
fetch('https://host.com', {headers: headers})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use some extension like Modify Headers and include in it your credentials data like you are including un postman.